# Angular 7 hide particular attribute inside ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor

I'm using a ngFor loop angular 7 I need to a hidden particular attribute(example userNo and UserType ) inside a ngFor loop.

```
emailId: "afsageg@dgvsf"
groupName: "dfsfgfdg"
mobileNo: "+91fyrtyrtyty"
userId: "ttrur"
userName: "srurttuidharan"
userNo: 2
userType: "rrhjty"
userTypeDisplay: "Operator Maker"

<tr *ngFor="let key of formData | keyvalue" >
    <td [hidden]="key.userNo">{{key.key | titlecase}}</td>
    <td>{{key.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden"?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem and what is the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td [hidden]="key.key==='userNo'">{{key.key | titlecase}}</td>
<td [hidden]="key.key==='userNo'">{{key.value}}</td> <!--if you also want to hide the value -->
```

Or you can use `*ngIf` instead of `[hidden]`

I would also suggest to rename your `key` to `object` (or something less generic even) as each iteration of the `*ngFor` holds an object and not just the key (hence why you can access key AND value)

So something like:

```
<tr *ngFor="let obj of formData | keyvalue" >
    <td [hidden]="obj.key==='userNo'">{{obj.key | titlecase}}</td>
    <td [hidden]="obj.key==='userNo'">{{obj.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

[Small Stackblitz to illustrate](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anpgv5)

Answer (score 0):

```
emailId: "afsageg@dgvsf"
groupName: "dfsfgfdg"
mobileNo: "+91fyrtyrtyty"
userId: "ttrur"
userName: "srurttuidharan"
userNo: 2
userType: "rrhjty"
userTypeDisplay: "Operator Maker"

<tr *ngFor="let key of formData | keyvalue" >
    <td [hidden]="key.userNo === true">{{key.key | titlecase}}</td>
    <td>{{key.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want hide an attribute you can do some like

```
<td [attrib]="key.userNo?'value':null">
```

If you want not show a text, you can do

```
<td>{{key.userNo?'':key.key | titlecase}}</td>
```

Others is use style.display

```
<td [style.display]="key.userNo?'none':null">
```

of *ngIf

```
<td *ngIf="!key.userNo">
```